# Does swift have class level static variables?

Tags: class, swift, static

How to declare static constant in class scope? such as

```
class let Constant: Double = 3.1415926
// I know that in class we use class modifier instead of static.
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Swift supports static type properties, including on classes, as of Swift 1.2:

```
class MyClass {
    static let pi = 3.1415926
}
```

If you need to have a class variable that is overridable in a subclass, you'll need to use a computed class property:

```
class MyClass {
    class var pi: Double { return 3.1415926 }
}

class IndianaClass : MyClass {
    override class var pi: Double { return 4 / (5 / 4) }
}
```

Comment: Is global variable available in other classes as well?(In the same module)

Comment: Yes, so long as they aren't marked `private`, they'll be available in any class in your module.

Comment: So in the xcodeproj,is it best practice to create a constant.swift file to include all the constants?(Unlike java,we do not need to create a new class)

Comment: Well, there aren't truly *best practices* yet, though there are lots of different ideas of what they should be. If a single file with all your constants makes the most sense for your project, go for it - that'd be roughly analogous to a "Constants.h" file in an Objective-C project.

Comment: As of Swift 1.2, static variables are also available - http://swiftdoc.org/type/Process/ .

Comment: @marius looks like only in `enums` though...

Comment: I see what you did there :-)

Comment: So here, are the "class var" declarations simply declarations of a subclass of MyClass which consists entirely of one variable ? What exactly is "class var" ?

Comment: Kudos for referencing the [Indiana Pi Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill)