# How to call a function each time a new tableViewCell is added to a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a method that returns a new color each time it is called and what I want to do is be able to color the rows with a new color each time a new one is added.

With the code below I only get `red` rows, the blue, green and yellow are never called.

Again, what I need to do is be able to color each row with one of the four colors in the array, the first row `red` the second `blue`, the third one `green` the fourth one `yellow` and then start coloring the fifth one `red` again, the sixth `blue` and so on.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    let myColors = [colorMyRed, colorMyBlue, colorMyGreen, colorMyYellow]

    var nextItemIndex = 0

    func color() -> UIColor {
        let result = myColors[nextItemIndex]
        nextItemIndex = nextItemIndex + 1
        return result
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        // how can I assign a new color to this variable 
        // each time awakeFromNib is called
        let myColor:UIColor = color()

        // these labels need to be colored with one of the
        // four colors each time a new row is added  
        labelPrice.textColor = myColor
        labelDiscount.textColor = myColor
        labelSavings.textColor = myColor
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `nextItemIndex` is an instance variable. Each time a new cell is created, it is initialized to zero. You need to make it static to make it work.

Comment: I don't think in Swift static works the same way it works in other languages.

Comment: Well, Swift sure has an awful syntax, but `static` works pretty much the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804066/does-swift-have-class-level-static-variables

Comment: Thank you for your help but I ended up re-structuring my code to do the coloring in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and worked. Thank you all.

Comment: It is the best aproac because awakeFromNib will not get called when tableView deques the cell.So it is better to maintain count in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did it that worked. Thank you all for your help.

**CustomCell.swift**

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {  

    var labelColor: UIColor! {  
        get {  
            return labelPrice.textColor  
        }  
        set {  
            labelPrice.textColor = newValue  
            labelDiscount.textColor = newValue  
            labelSavings.textColor = newValue  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**ViewController.swif (***cellForRowAtIndexPath***)**

```
    let myColors = [colorMyRed, colorMyBlue, colorMyGreen, colorMyYellow]  

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        let myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell  

        let nextItemIndex = indexPath.row % myColors.count  
        myCustomCell.labelColor = myColors[nextItemIndex]  
        return myCustomCell  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can accomplish it in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** function of UITableViewCell

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIndentifier") as UITableViewCell!
    // Configure the cell...
    switch(indexPath.row) {
    case 0, 4, 8, 12:
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Red"
        break
    case 1, 5, 9, 13:
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Blue"
        break
    case 2, 6, 10, 14:
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Green"
        break
    case 3, 7, 11, 15 :
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Yellow"
        break
    default:
        cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Black"
        break
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private struct Colors {
  static var currentIndex = 0 // 1
  static func getNewColor() -> UIColor { 
    let number = Colors.currentIndex % 4 // 2
    Colors.currentIndex += 1 // 3
    switch number { // 4
      case 0:
        return UIColor.redColor()
      case 1:
        return UIColor.blueColor()
      case 2:
        return UIColor.greenColor()
      case 3:
        return UIColor.yellowColor()
      default:
        fatalError() // should not encounter this case
    }
  }
}
```

Create a struct that will act as your "colour dispenser". The code is relatively straightforward:

1. You declare an integer variable that you'll use to keep track of which colour you should use next.
2. The `number` variable is the `currentIndex` modulus 4, meaning it'll contain a value between 0 and 3.
3. Increment the `currentIndex` property. This ensures that the next time you call this method you'll get a new `number` result.

The `getNewColor` method will give a new colour each time the method is called.

For instance, you can use this in your current code like so:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  super.awakeFromNib()
  let myColor = Colors.getNewColor()
  labelPrice.textColor = myColor
  labelDiscount.textColor = myColor
  labelSavings.textColor = myColor
}
```